# How to do Graphql request in Protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, graphql

I need to do handle **Graphql** request in protractor. I have tried using `protractor-http-client` but it's giving `Internal server error`. Can anyone suggest how to use **Graphql** request in protractor?

```
const http = new HttpClient('<MY_BASE_URL>');

const query = gql `
 query currentUserQuery {
  currentUser {
    email
    id
  }
 }`;

const postResponse = http.post('/graphql', {
    query: query,
    operationName: 'currentUser',
    variables: {}
  }, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
  }
).then(data => {
   console.log('data', data);
  }, err => {
   console.log('err is: ', err);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock all backend requests in Jasmine, as Protractor is for testing front-end part only (Angular)

Comment: Protractor is for E2E testing. And also, there is a package `protractor-http-client` for sending the request to APIs. Can you explain the answer what you are suggesting??

Comment: In this case try to add simple request first and check your logs on backend. Maybe you're missing some headers or params.

Comment: Or in case everything is fine on your side, you could try to use different package, like [protractor-api-resource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-api-resource)